# serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout ,arduino

Tags: arduino-esp8266

[image: 1]

I have the following error when uploading, what is the reason for this?

I replaced the cable and changed the upload speed to 9600, but the problem remained

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows11 Try to update the CP210x USB UART Bridge Driver. It might help: [SI Labs Driver](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads)